# Remove gap to the right of a list

Tags: html, css, list, icons, html-lists

I am trying to make a web page that looks similar to a mobile phones home page. I would like it to reorder the icons depending on the size of the screen.
what I have so far is bellow

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
  border-radius: 1em;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem with this code is that when you resize the window and the list items move to the next line, you can be left with a big gap on the right hand side. Is there a way I can distribute this extra space either by centering the list as whole or between the list items? I would like to avoid centering the icons so I can keep them all aligned both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1):

I change from `inline-block` to `float:left` and i move your `padding` to `img`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  animation: FadeIn 1.3s;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 13.42%;
}
ul li:not(:first-child){
  margin-left: 1%;
}
img {
  width: 82%;
  padding: 8%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes this is close. But this is causing the items to be aligned to center also. These I would like to keep left aligned so that it forms a grid.

Comment: then you need to set width for your `li`, then use `@media`

Comment: this is the updated one, i use `float` instead of `inline-block`.

Comment: check the snippet now, i set width using percentage.

Comment: I was after something that will create a smooth transition between screen sizes rather than the quantised nature of using a media query. Also the icons shouldn't change there size as the screen size changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and added media queries. I hope this would help.

CSS Added:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
  ul {
    padding: 10%;
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  animation: FadeIn 1.3s;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7);
  border-radius: 1em;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
  ul {
    padding: 10%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img class=link src="https://www.google.com.au/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```